# RDD from Dataset results in a Serialization Error with Spark 2.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, databricks, apache-spark-2.0

I have an RDD that I created from a Dataset using Databricks notebook.

When I try to get concrete values from it, it simply fails with a serialization error message.

Here is where I get my data (PageCount is a Case class) :

```
val pcDf = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM pagecounts20160801")
val pcDs = pcDf.as[PageCount]
val pcRdd = pcDs.rdd
```

Then when I do :

```
pcRdd.take(10)
```

I get the following exception :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0 in stage 82.0 (TID 2474) had a not serializable result: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection
```

Even though the same attempt on the Dataset works :

```
pcDs.take(10)
```

EDIT :

here is the complete stacktrace

```
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection, value: <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1, name: appendPartitionColumns, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD, name: readFunction, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD, FileScanRDD[1095] at )
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: _rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@502bfe49)
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@51dc790)
    - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@502bfe49))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[1096] at )
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: _rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@52ce8951)
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@57850f0)
    - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@52ce8951))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[1097] at )
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: _rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@7e99329a)
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@792f3145)
    - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@7e99329a))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[1098] at )
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset, name: rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset, Invalid tree; null:
null)
    - field (class: lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c121.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: pcDs, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)
    - object (class lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c121.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c121.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@3482035d)
    - field (class: lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c121.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$PageCount, name: $outer, type: class lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c121.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c121.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$PageCount, PageCount(de.b,Spezial:Linkliste/Datei:Playing_card_diamond_9.svg,1,6053))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Llineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c121.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$PageCount;, size 10)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1452)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1440)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1439)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1665)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1620)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1609)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1881)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1894)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1311)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1285)
    at lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c137.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:33)
    at lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c137.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:40)
    at lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c137.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c137.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:44)
    at lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c137.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at lineb9de310f01c84f49b76c6c6295a1393c137.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
```

Comment: Does your `PageCount` class implements serializable?

Comment: Is PageCount a case class ?

Comment: It is a case class as @eliasah suggested so it is by default serializable. In fact since it works for datasets I think there shouldn't be any serialization issue ? or is there a difference regarding serialization ?

Comment: Can you print out some more line of the error log ?

Comment: @eliasah just added

Answer (score 1):

1. **PageCount** class definitely has non-serializable reference (some non-transient non-serializable member, or maybe parent type with the same problem). Inability to serialize the object given let Spark to try to serialize enclosing scope, up to more and more its members, including the member of FileFormat somewhere up the road, - the projection generated by Janino (which is not serializable by design).
   This is just a side effect of bad target object (PageCount) serialization.

Relevant code from spark [FileFormat.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat.scala) (should be marked with @transient to really avoid serialization in case if "appendPartitionColumns" was once materialized)

```
// Using lazy val to avoid serialization
  private lazy val appendPartitionColumns =
    GenerateUnsafeProjection.generate(fullSchema, fullSchema)
```

This "non-expected" serialization above will never happen though in a regular scenario, until user-defined types serialization succeeds.

2. Spark **RDD** (raw type! no global schema for it is known to Spark) serialization involves complete objects serialization (object data and object "schema", type) during materialization. Default mechanism of serialization is Java serializer (so that you can try to serialize **PageCount** using Java serializer, and this maybe reveal the problem with this type), and may be replaced with more efficient Kryo serializer (which will serialize object into blob though, so that we will loose the schema, and will not be able to apply sqls requiring columns access). This is why RDD access triggers serialization issues
3. **Dataframes** / **Datasets** are strong-typed, they are bound to schema which is known to Spark. Therefore, for Spark, no need to pass the objects structure between nodes, only data is being passed.
   This is the reason why there's no problem to materialize Dataset / Dataframe of underlying object type PageCount.